# Calling a custom FLASH method from IE7 & IE8

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to call a custom method of an embedded flash like so:

> var flash =
>   navigation_get_flash_movie_object('main');
>         if (flash) {
>             flash.continentOut(id);         }

Which works great in Chrome ans Safari, but fails utterly in IE7 & IE8.  The browsers throws an error that the object doesn't have such a method.

I am using the example from  http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/, and now that I've tested it, it also fails at it's testing page as well http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashGetObject/

Does anyone have a better way to invoke custom functions in a Flash object from Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ExternalInterface API Docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).  They use this method:

```
 function thisMovie(movieName) {
     if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
         return window[movieName];
     } else {
         return document[movieName];
     }
 }
```

So you would do this:

```
var flash = thisMovie('main'); if (flash) { flash.continentOut(id); }
```

(I'm assuming of course that you're using `ExternalInterface.addCallback()` to define `continentOut`)

Here's another option:

```
 function thisMovie(movieName) {
     return document[movieName] || window[movieName];
 }
```

Personally, this seems better because it doesn't use browser sniffing and would be future-compatible, but that's just me.